# Complex Core Data predicate with to-many relation

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have 3 entities. Folder, Feed & FeedItem

I need to fetch Folders which have feeds and feeds which have unread FeedItems

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" feeds.@count > 0 AND feeds.feedItems.unread == 0 "];
```

I get this error

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'

How do I construct such a predicate? Is it possible at all?

Comment: You might try looking in the `userInfo` of the exception object for a predicate you can examine to see what part of that expression was invalid. `predicateWithFormat:` creates a tree of NSPredicates (made of NSComparisonPredicates and NSCompoundPredicates, in your case) and returns the root of that tree; if the exception object has a predicate in its `userInfo`, it will be one of the nodes of that tree, corresponding to some part of that expression.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It doesn't like `feeds.feedItems.unread==0` because `feeds` and `feedItems` return a set so the predicate doesn't know which object to test.

Try `ANY feeds.feedItems.unread==0`.

However, you're going about this backwards. It would be easier to fetch all `FeedItem` where `unread==0` and then ask for each fetched item's `feed.folder` to get the folder.

Complex predicates are usually a bad idea because you can never predict the resource consumption of the search they perform as the object graph grows in complexity and the data itself grows in size. You should walk relationships instead when you can.

---

### Update:

Looking at this again it looks like you need a SUBQUERY. Try:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(0 != SUBQUERY(feeds, $x, (0 != SUBQUERY($x.feedItems, $y, $y.unread==0).@count)).@count)"];
```

Subqueries are poorly documented but they are essentially nested predicates. They have the format:

```
SUBQUERY(objects, singleObjectVariable, expression-for-single-object)
```

I believe that subqueries return sets so you can use any of the set operators on them and you can nest them. When you nest them, they walk the relationship graph so you can make them arbitrarily deep.

Comment: I tried this, but get exception 'multiple to-many keys not allowed here'. The reason i cannot do it backwards is because feedItems could be huge.

Comment: Tried the subquery method. getting this error Unable to generate SQL for predicate (0 != SUBQUERY(feeds, $x, 0 != SUBQUERY($x.feedItems, $y, $y.unread == 0).@count).@count) (problem on RHS)'

Comment: You dropped a parenthesis. It should be '(0 != SUBQUERY(feeds, $x, ...(...0 != SUBQUERY($x.feedItems, $y, $y.unread == 0).@count).@count)` where "..." delineates the missing paren.

Comment: Poorly documented? That must be the understatement of the year!