# Updating/Inserting existing objects in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` with a `UITableView` which displays a list of folders and associated unread counts for each item in that folder. I'd like to insert/delete folders w/ animation from the tableView based on the unread count during a sync/refresh (on a background thread utilizing `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`). Folders with no unread items should fade out, and existing folders with new unread items should fade in.

Currently using the `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` method does not do this unless the tableView is completely reloaded, or the app is relaunched, which is not ideal.

Is `NSFetchedResultsController` not the way to do this? My initial idea was to create a separate Core Data entity that only holds the folders with unread items, and add/remove folders from that, but that just seems hokey.

My `NSPredicate` looks something like:

`ANY items.unread == 1`

**Update:**
The above NSPredicate works fine and grabs the objects that I expect it to. My problem is that if the app launches and FolderX has 0 unread items, it does not appear. If I then refresh (goes out and parses a JSON file in a background thread) and FolderX now has 25 unread items, it will **not** automatically fade in or trigger `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert` and since it wasn't included in the first place, it also doesn't trigger `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` which is why I thought the solution was to create a separate Entity that only holds Folders with unread items and add/remove from that during sync.

I just feel like I'm missing something painfully obvious.

**Update 2:**
I've simplified the problem as much as I can by removing the influence of my own app, I'm able to replicate it in the default Core Data template in Xcode.

The New Problem:
There is a single Entity named "Event" with no relationships and two properties, "Date" and "unreadCount". I have NSFetchedResultsController set up with an NSPredicate that looks like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"unreadCount < 10"];
```

Every time a new object is added, it is created with an unreadCount of 15, then all existing objects are decremented by 1. This is done on a separate ManagedObjectContext (to replicate background processing, but is all done on the main thread).

I've implemented the controllerWillChangeContent and related methods, and what I expected to happen was that after an existing object (with unreadCount of 15) is decremented 5 times (to now be 10) it should be inserted into the tableView because it now matches the predicate. This is not at all what happens, the object does not appear at all unless the app is restarted.

I've attached a sample project, simply run it and click the Add button a few times (nothing will happen). Restart the app and you will see a handful of objects now in the tableView, if you click the Add button a few more times those objects will remove themselves, but new objects will not get added.

If NSFetchedResultsController is not the solution to get this behavior to work, then what is?

Sample Project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/521075/BGUpdating.zip

Comment: what was your solution to this problem? Because I have a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776371/gmgridview-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-data-not-updating-reloading

Answer (score 1):

Your predicate will not work crossing two or more to-many relationships. You have at present:

```
type == folder AND ANY (set of folders).(set of items).unread == 1
```

You can't use ANY to transverse an arbitrary number of relationships. Instead, you probably need a [subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487267/complex-core-data-predicate-with-to-many-relation/3487632#3487632) like:

```
type == folder AND (0!=SUBQUERY(folder,$f,0!=SUBQUERY($f.items,$i,$i.unread==1).@count).@count)
```

I think you maybe performing the fetch on the wrong entity. If you are presenting a table of `Folder` objects, you should be performing the fetch on the `Folder` entity. That alone would simplify everything. Your predicate would then be just:

```
ANY items.unread==1
```

Comment: I've updated my question to be a little more simple and clear, and also removed the to-many relationship, and fetching the Folder entity directly but still not getting the results I expect.

Comment: The problem then appears to be with the notification following the merge. The merge should trigger the FRC to notify its delegate that something has changed. Make sure you have inverse relationships set in the data model so that a change in Folder or Item object is reflected on the other side of the relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've dug down a bit deeper and once again updated my question to be even more specific by removing the influence of my own app model.